# hamburger menu is not showing in mobile view

Tags: plugins, css, html

I run a website using WordPress. The hello elementor theme was utilised. My header desktop view header menu is displaying appropriately, which is my concern.but the hamburger menu in mobile view does not display appropriately.the solution.[image: this is mobile view screenshot]